# How to display a console window in C# Unit Test?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, debugging, console

I want to be able to display a console window at will in my C# unit tests that I can later address in my code to print statements to. is there a system command to support for this? My intention is debug purposes but I don't want to use log4net or some other text/xml file for accomplishing that.

Answer (score 10):

Just use `Console.WriteLine`. Every unit test runner that I've used has captured console output automatically - you don't need an actual console window for that.

Answer (score 2):

If i understand your question correctly, follow the steps mentioned below

1- Right click the console project

2- Go to the Application section

3- In the dropdown named "Output Type" select "Console Application".

4- Save and run the application

what this will do is, it will open the console along with the winform. Whereever you will write Console.Writeline, it will show in the console. (Your form will keep on running as it is.)

Answer (score 0):

If you really need a console window, consider access AllocConsole via p/Invoke:

http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32/AllocConsole.html